# Hoy can I get Shared Access Signature from Notification Hub throught Terraform?

Tags: terraform, azure-notificationhub, terraform-provider-azure

I have this Terraform resource:

```
resource "azurerm_notification_hub" "notificationhub" {
  name                                = "notification-hub-${var.environment}"
  namespace_name                      = azurerm_notification_hub_namespace.notificationhubnamespace.name
  resource_group_name                 = azurerm_resource_group.resourcegroup.name
  location                            = var.azure_location
}
```

This block works fine and it creates a hub on Azure.

But.. How can I get "**DefaultFullSharedAccessSignature**" from Terraform?

[image]

I don't find any documentation on Terraform https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/azurerm/r/notification_hub.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found a resource from terraform "**azurerm_notification_hub_authorization_rule**"

```
resource "azurerm_notification_hub_authorization_rule" "rule" {
  name                                = "Full"
  notification_hub_name               = azurerm_notification_hub.notificationhub.name
  namespace_name                      = azurerm_notification_hub_namespace.notificationhubnamespace.name
  resource_group_name                 = azurerm_resource_group.resourcegroup.name
  manage                              = true
  send                                = true
  listen                              = true

  depends_on                          = [azurerm_notification_hub.notificationhub]

}
```

And I can access to azurerm_notification_hub_authorization_rule.rule.primary.primary_access_key

Comment: As someone who has spent a lot of time with terraform and Notification Hubs, I can confirm this answer.